# How to fix errors in building Android : Use of undeclared identifier ‘V4L2_COM_CMD_FLUSH’

Tags: java, c

I am building an Android ROM, but I am having trouble in the middle of the compilation.,What do I need to adjust?

This is base on a useably rom‘s device tree, I want to use another rom,so i made it to another rom. But when I successfully bring up and start compiling, it will be stuck in this error.

Here is the device tree link
https://github.com/lemonbigbig/device_xiaomi_vince

```
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8996/mm-video-v412/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_v412.cpp:3401:15:
    error: use of undeclared identifier'V4L2_QCOM_CMD_FLUSH'
        dec.cmd = V4L2_QCOM_CMD_FLUSH;
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8996/mm-video-v412/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_v412.cpp:4145:26:
error: use of undeclared identifier 'V4L2 HPEG VIDEO H264 LEVEL UNKNOWN'
       case V4L2 MPEG VIDEO_H264_LEVEL_UNKNOWN:
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `V4L2_QCOM_CMD_FLUSH` before you use it. I am not sure what the appropriate value is for your kernel, but I found a definition here:

https://github.com/tonight0210/device/blob/a7a7fa827a44dc04571616d8f41e417de753eee5/google/crosshatch/sdm845/kernel-headers/linux/videodev2.h#L1067